# Circle chart with repulsive circles

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I tried a simple bubble chart which have repulsive functionalities but the whole force simulation thing not working I am new to D3 please help

The circles are still overlapping please help with this.

```js
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'd3Project';

  dataset = [

    [34, 78, 14],
    [109, 280, 20],
    [310, 120, 22],
    [79, 411, 32],
    [420, 220, 23],
    [233, 145, 26],
    [333, 96, 27],
    [222, 333, 24],
    [78, 320, 35],
    [21, 123, 12],
    [22, 126, 40]
  ];

  dataSet: any = [

    [14, 78],
    [20, 280],
    [22, 120],
    [32, 411],
    [23, 220],
    [26, 145],
    [27, 96],
    [24, 333],
    [35, 320],
    [12, 123],
    [40, 126]
  ];

  w = 1000;
  h = 500;
  padding = 30;

  xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(this.dataset, (d) => d[0])])
    .range([this.padding, this.w - this.padding]);

  yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(this.dataset, (d) => d[1])])
    .range([this.h - this.padding, this.padding]);

  data = [14, 20, 22, 32, 23, 26, 27, 24, 35, 43, 40];

  ngOnInit() {

    const svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", this.w)
      .attr("height", this.h)
      // .attr('x',this.w) 
      // .attr('y',this.h)
      .attr('viewBox', '-700 -300 ' + (this.w + 700) + ' ' + (this.h + 200))
    // viewBox="0 0 100 100"

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation().nodes(this.dataset)

    //add forces
    //we're going to add a charge to each node 
    //also going to add a centering force

    simulation
      .force("charge_force", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
      .force("center_force", d3.forceCenter(this.w / 2, this.h / 2))
      .on('tick', ticked);

    function ticked() {
      node.attr("cx", function(d) {
          return d[0];
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return d[1];
        });
    }

    let node = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(this.dataset)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      //  .attr('cx',(d) =>  Math.round( this.xScale(d[0]) ) )
      //  .attr('cy',(d) =>  Math.round( this.yScale(d[1]) ) )
      .attr('r', (d) => d[2])
      .attr('position', 'relative')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + [this.w / 2, this.h / 2] + ')')
      .style('fill', (d) => {
        if (d[2] % 2) return 'purple';
        else if (d[2] < 200) return 'red';
        else
          return 'orange';
      })
      .append('title')
      .text((d) => 'radius: ' + d[2]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure (an array of arrays)  is wrong. The [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#simulation_nodes) is clear about the data structure to be passed to the simulation:

> Each node must be an **object**. (emphasis mine)

We can turn your data into an array of objects with this, for instance:

```
dataset = dataset.map(function(d) {
  return {
    data: d
  }
});
```

Here, I'm putting the inner arrays as a value in the `data` property. Then, the simulation will populate all other properties (`x`, `y`, `index`, `vx` and `vy`).

Also, you have a more subtle mistake: your `node` selection is a selection of `<title>` elements, not `<circle>` elements. Because of that, the `ticked` function won't work. So, break the `node` selection, like this:

```
let node = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  //etc...

node.append('title')
  //etc...
```

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
dataset = [

  [34, 78, 14],
  [109, 280, 20],
  [310, 120, 22],
  [79, 411, 32],
  [420, 220, 23],
  [233, 145, 26],
  [333, 96, 27],
  [222, 333, 24],
  [78, 320, 35],
  [21, 123, 12],
  [22, 126, 40]
];

dataset = dataset.map(function(d) {
  return {
    data: d
  }
});

w = 600;
h = 400;
padding = 30;

const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(dataset)
  .force("charge_force", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-50))
  .force("center_force", d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2))
  .on('tick', ticked);

function ticked() {
  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
}

let node = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  //  .attr('cx',(d) =>  Math.round( this.xScale(d[0]) ) )
  //  .attr('cy',(d) =>  Math.round( this.yScale(d[1]) ) )
  .attr('r', (d) => d.data[2])
  .style('fill', (d) => {
    if (d.data[2] % 2) return 'purple';
    else if (d.data[2] < 200) return 'red';
    else
      return 'orange';
  });

node.append('title')
  .text((d) => 'radius: ' + d.data[2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```